# Unable to save data in database using JPA in SpringBoot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-webflux

I'm working on microservice based Java application using JDK 1.8, Spring 5 and SpringBoot 2.0. I'm using JPA in application for CRUD. I have following method to update an existing record with cart id in database (PostGres) :-

```
@Override
@CachePut(value = CommerceConnectorConstants.CommerceCache.COMMERCE_CACHE_TENANT_USER_DATA_MAP)
public Mono<CommerceTenantUser> updateCartId(String tenantId, String userId, String cartId) {
    logger.info("cartId->"+cartId);

    final TenantUserKey commerce = getCommerceObj(tenantId, userId);
    Optional <CommerceTenantUser> tenantUser = commerceTenantUserRepository.findById(commerce);

    return tenantUser.map(tenantUserObj -> updateCartIdAndRefreshMap(tenantUserObj, cartId)).orElse(Mono.empty());

}

private Mono<CommerceTenantUser> updateCartIdAndRefreshMap(CommerceTenantUser tenantUserObj, String cartId) {
    tenantUserObj.setCartId(cartId);

    final Mono<CommerceTenantUser> commerceTenantUser = asyncRunner
            .one(() -> commerceTenantUserRepository.saveAndFlush(tenantUserObj))
            .doOnNext(value -> commerceCacheService.refreshMap())
            .doOnError(error -> logger.error("Error while persisting Cart Id: {}", error))
            .map(commerceTenantUserObj -> commerceTenantUserObj);

    return commerceTenantUser;

}
```

My issue is in one of the application flow, I'm unable to update the cart id. I tried to debug the flow many times, I can clearly see that the call is happening to this method and I can **log cart id value** in console as well but in the end the update of cart id never actually happens in database.
Please note this same method for updating the cart id is happening in other flows of application where cart id eventually gets saved in database (except my flow) so I guess there is no issue with the implementation logic of saving.

**Following is the flow where this method invocation is happening but not saving in database :-**

@Override
  public Mono verifyCredentialsforBasicAuthorization(Map  requestInfo) {

```
Tuple4<String, String, WebClient, String> serviceConnectionDetails = commerceConnectorHelper.verifyCredentialsforBasicAuthorization(requestInfo);

if(!StringUtils.isBlank(serviceConnectionDetails._1)) {
    logger.info("Calling cart id update service...");

       return serviceConnectionDetails._3
    .post()
         .uri(builder -> builder.path(serviceConnectionDetails._1)
             .queryParam(CommerceConnectorConstants.CartParams.OLD_CART_ID, serviceConnectionDetails._4)
             .build())
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(CartModel.class)
         .map(response ->
         {
           return repositoryDetails.updateCartId(requestInfo.get(CommerceConnectorConstants.HttpHeaders.TENANT_ID).get(),
               requestInfo.get(CommerceConnectorConstants.HttpHeaders.TENANT_USER_ID).get(), response.getGuid()).then(Mono.just(response));
         }) .then(repositoryDetails.updateCommerceUserId(requestInfo.get(CommerceConnectorConstants.HttpHeaders.TENANT_ID).get(),
             requestInfo.get(CommerceConnectorConstants.HttpHeaders.TENANT_USER_ID).get(),
             requestInfo.get(CommerceConnectorConstants.AuthorizationParams.AUTHORIZATION_USERNAME).get()))

     .then(serviceConnectionDetails._3
         .get()
         .uri(serviceConnectionDetails._2)
         .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
         .retrieve()
         .bodyToMono(UserProfile.class)
         .doOnNext(value -> logger.info("Called User Profile service {}", value.getCustomerId()))
         .doOnError(error -> logger.error("Error while calling User Profile service: {}", error)));


}
else
//Update Commerce User Id
;

//User Profile Call
return serviceConnectionDetails._3
    .get()
    .uri(serviceConnectionDetails._2)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(UserProfile.class)
    .doOnNext(value -> logger.info("Called User Profile service {}", value.getCustomerId()))
        .doOnError(error -> logger.error("Error while calling User Profile service: {}", error));
```

}

If you notice, I'm calling this method **repositoryDetails.updateCartId** and passing all the required parameters including the cart id by using **response.getGuid()**. The method is executed in the end but eventually it does not saves the data in table. I tried really hard but not able to figure out the issue. This is the problem with asynchronous calls using the Java Reactive programming. I would really appreciate if you can help me in figuring out issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the root cause of it. I was suppose to call update once only on same Entity using JPA. In my case I was calling twice individually to update 2 different columns in same Entity.